# sed replace with eval

Tags: bash, sed

What I want to do

```
replace: '1000'
with: (a random number) shuf -i 500-1500 -n 1
```

`shuf ..` shall be exectued for every occurence of `1000`

What I've tried

```
sed -i 's/1000/$(shuf -i 500-1500 -n 1)/g'
```

But I just takes the eval as string

Answer (score 5):

It happens because single quotes escape the meaning of `$` and the command substitution is not occurring.

**Solution** is to use double quotes

```
sed -i "s/1000/$(shuf -i 500-1500 -n 1)/g"
```

- The double quotes retains the special meaning of `$` and all other special characters.
- [Read more about bash double quoted strings.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes)

---

To replace each occurrence with different values from `shuf`, you can loop over the file using basic `while` and replace the string as

```
while read line
do
    echo "$line" | sed -i "s/1000/$(shuf -i 500-1500 -n 1)/g" >> output_temp
done    
mv output_temp original_file
```

- The `while` loop reads each line from the file and replaces them.
- `mv`replaces the original file with the temp file.

Comment: It will replace every 1000 by **same random number** not a new random every time.

Comment: @anubhava I addressed only this part it seems *But I just takes the eval as string*. I will update my answer then

Comment: Updated to replace with new random numbers for each occurrence.

Comment: It will be faster, if you move the `>> output_temp` redirection in the whole loop rather than write for each line.   i.e.    
 `while read line; do echo "$line" | sed -i "s/1000/$(shuf -i 500-1500 -n 1)/g"; done >> output_temp && mv output_temp original_file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk` command to replace `1000` by a new random number from `shuf` output:

```
awk -v cmd="shuf -i 500-1500 -n 1" '{
   while(index($0, "1000")) {
      cmd | getline rnum;
      close(cmd);
      sub("1000", rnum, $0)
   }
} 1' file
```

---

**Update:** A faster version of same using `rand()` function in `gnu-awk`:

```
awk '{while(sub("1000", int(10000 * rand()), $0));} 1' file
```

Comment: I've updated answer with a faster variant of gnu-awk

Comment: `awk '{while(sub("1000", int(10000 * rand()), $0))x}1`, should be quicker as there is one less function call